# How do I use a SELECT ... AS in a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here is a piece of SQL code that does not work:

```
SELECT bl.regn_id,
   RTRIM(LTRIM(dv.dv_id))   + '_' + RTRIM(LTRIM(bl.regn_id)) AS bu_regn,
   (SELECT COUNT (em.em_id) 
      FROM em 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN bl bl_s ON em.bl_id = bl_s.bl_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN irs_self_cert_em  ON  em.em_id = irs_self_cert_em.em_id
      WHERE dv.dv_id = em.dv_id
      AND bl.bl_id = bl_s.bl_id
      AND irs_self_cert_em.date_cert_loc >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
      AND (em.date_last_update_cads >= (select date_last_update_completed FROM ddi_completed WHERE ddi_id='TRA_CADS_EM'))          
    ) AS certified 
FROM bl       
    CROSS JOIN dv 
    WHERE bl.status = 'A'  AND (certified > 0 )
```

I receive the error: "Lookup Error - SQL Server Database Error: Invalid column name 'certified'."

As you can see I use a subquery within the SELECT statement and give it the name 'certified'. I then try to use that value in the WHERE clause.

Can someone suggest and alternative way of accomplishing this?

Many thanks,
Matt

Comment: You can not use an aliased column in a `WHERE` clause. I would create another subquery to add criteria to that field.

Comment: You will have to include that entire SELECT again

Comment: you can't use column alias in where condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use an aliased (calculated) column in a WHERE clause. I would create another subquery to add criteria to that field.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT
        bl.regn_id,
        RTRIM(LTRIM(dv.dv_id))   + '_' + RTRIM(LTRIM(bl.regn_id)) AS bu_regn,
       (
            SELECT
                COUNT(em.em_id) AS [Count]
            FROM
                em LEFT OUTER JOIN bl AS bl_s
                    ON
                        em.bl_id = bl_s.bl_id LEFT OUTER JOIN irs_self_cert_em
                            ON
                                em.em_id = irs_self_cert_em.em_id
            WHERE
                dv.dv_id = em.dv_id
                    AND
                bl.bl_id = bl_s.bl_id
                AND
                    irs_self_cert_em.date_cert_loc >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
                AND
                    (em.date_last_update_cads >= (select date_last_update_completed FROM ddi_completed WHERE ddi_id='TRA_CADS_EM'))          
        ) AS certified
    FROM
        bl CROSS JOIN dv 
    WHERE
        bl.status = 'A'
) AS temp
    WHERE
        certified > 0
```

---

I also tried to clean up the query a bit. You were using `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s with criteria on the right had side table, so it was truly an `INNER JOIN` (`INNER JOIN`s will work more efficiently / quickly). Check it out and let me know if this works for you as expected.

```
;WITH
cte AS
(
    SELECT
        bl.regn_id,
        RTRIM(LTRIM(dv.dv_id))   + '_' + RTRIM(LTRIM(bl.regn_id)) AS bu_regn
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY bl.regn_id, dv.dv_id, bl.regn_id ORDER BY bl.regn_id) AS [Certified]
    FROM
        dv INNER JOIN em
            ON
                dv.dv_id = em.dv_id INNER JOIN JOIN bl
                    ON
                        em.bl_id = bl.bl_id INNER JOIN JOIN irs_self_cert_em
                            ON
                                em.em_id = irs_self_cert_em.em_id
    WHERE
        bl.status = N'A'
            AND
        irs_self_cert_em.date_cert_loc >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
            AND
        (em.date_last_update_cads >= (select date_last_update_completed FROM ddi_completed WHERE ddi_id='TRA_CADS_EM')
)
SELECT
    DISTINCT
    *
FROM
    cte
WHERE
    Certified > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Without having tables structure (ex: to know which id is unique) some data related to them and the way you want the output, it's hard to say and test but I went with something that look like this :

```
SELECT bl.regn_id,
   RTRIM(LTRIM(dv.dv_id))   + '_' + RTRIM(LTRIM(bl.regn_id)) AS bu_regn,
   result.certified
FROM bl       
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT em.bl_id AS bl_id, COUNT (em.em_id) as certified
      FROM em 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN bl bl_s ON em.bl_id = bl_s.bl_id
      INNER JOIN irs_self_cert_em  ON  em.em_id = irs_self_cert_em.em_id 
               AND irs_self_cert_em.date_cert_loc >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
     GROUP BY em.bl_id
     HAVING COUNT (em.em_id) > 0
    ) AS result ON result.bl_id = bl.bl_id
INNER JOIN em ON result.bl_id = em.bl_id 
         AND (em.date_last_update_cads >= 
     (SELECT date_last_update_completed FROM ddi_completed WHERE ddi_id='TRA_CADS_EM'))
CROSS JOIN dv ON dv.dv_id = em.dv_id      
WHERE bl.status = 'A'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT bl.regn_id,
   RTRIM(LTRIM(dv.dv_id))   + '_' + RTRIM(LTRIM(bl.regn_id)) AS bu_regn,
   S.certified
FROM bl       
    CROSS JOIN dv 
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT (em.em_id) as certified
      FROM em 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN bl bl_s ON em.bl_id = bl_s.bl_id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN irs_self_cert_em  ON  em.em_id = irs_self_cert_em.em_id
      WHERE dv.dv_id = em.dv_id
      AND bl.bl_id = bl_s.bl_id
      AND irs_self_cert_em.date_cert_loc >= DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())
      AND (em.date_last_update_cads >= (select date_last_update_completed FROM ddi_completed WHERE ddi_id='TRA_CADS_EM'))          
    ) AS S
    WHERE bl.status = 'A'  AND (S.certified > 0 )
```